# Safely deleting .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

**Situation:**

I am a beginner in Ruby on Rails and RVM (and apparently in Linux systems too, given to nature of this question). I created a directory to host my Rails project, but mistakenly created a gemset in the upper level directory.

I deleted the gemset using

`rvm gemset delete myset`

but when I move away and back the directory, the gemset is recreated.

**Questions:**

1. Is the gemset recreated because of the .ruby-gemset file?
2. Is it safe to manually delete the .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset files?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, since the *rvm* observes the current dir for the **.ruby-gemset**, **.ruby-version**,  or **.rvmrc**.
2. Yes, you can, and it will lead to that *rvm* will not do actions required for the found out the config files. You have to just place the files into the proper folder, and touch not the gemsets themselves. i.e. it will not affect on placement of the gemset inside the *rvm*.

Comment: So I assume **.ruby-version** and **.ruby-gemset** can also me moved/copied to another directory (if I want to use the same version and gems). Is that right?

Comment: @sargas yes, it will not affect on placement of the gemset inside the rvm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can safely delete them from the upper folder.

Those files are simply configurations which are used to enable a specified ruby version (or gemset) for a folder 'tree' like a Rails application.